# What does =< mean in a batch file after SET /P and variable name?

Tags: batch-file

So my friend gave me a batch file he wanted me to check if everything is correct, but I've got no clue what `=<` does in this.

```
:artthou_54
mode 50,20
cls
set videopath=0
title Art thou sure?
set /p videopath=<\DataTron\Ainstro\YePathToVido.dat
if %videopath%=="" echo Video Path = %videopath%
if %videopath%=="C:\Vodie" echo It seems you have the same path as the creator
set /p videopath="Would you like to open %VideoPath%? (Y/N): "
mode 50,20
if %videopath%==Y goto videohole-b
if %videopath%==N goto videohole
if %videopath%==y goto videohole-b
if %videopath%==n goto videohole
if %videopath%==back goto videohole-c
if %videopath%==exit exit
goto Art-thou-unsure
```

Comment: Type `set /?` to see normal usage. `<` redirects the contents of a file instead of typing. See https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/12/command-prompt-cheat-sheet.html for a Command Prompt Cheat Sheet.

Comment: Does it make more sense when it's written correctly? `Set /P "videopath=" 0< "DataTron\Ainstro\YePathToVido.dat"`?

Answer (score 3):

That line sets the first line of YePathToVido.dat to the variable `videopath`.

---

Normally, `set /p` gets input from the user and reads in until it receives a `CRLF`. 

However, `<` redirects input from the specified file and sends it to the `set /p` command. Since `set /p` reads until it receives a `CRLF`, this effectively tells the command to read from the start of the file until the end of the first line.

---

On a side note, those first two `if` statements are incorrect because batch compares everything on both sides of the `==`, *including the quotes*. Those lines need to change to `if "%videopath%"==""` and `if "%videopath%"=="C:\Vodie"`, respectively.

Comment: Yes, but if I were to change the lines to `"if "%videopath%"=="C:\Vodie"` then after closing the batch file it would erase all of the variables and paths that we need

Comment: @ShockedCoder - Variables get unset after the script ends and the command line closes. Quotes being present is completely unrelated, and your script _will_ throw an error if nothing is provided to `%videopath%`.

Comment: But I don't want the variables to get unset.

Comment: @ShockedCoder - As long as the command prompt window stays open, the variables will never get unset. `%videopath%` gets read in from the first line of YePathToVido.dat and then immediately gets overwritten three lines later when you ask if you want to open the path. After that, the variable doesn't change again in the code you've posted.